How to navigate to screens in tab navigation on web in React Native?
I am trying to navigate to my (tabs)/index.tsx screen from a different screen outside of the (tabs) folder on the web version of my app. It works fine on mobile. I have tried importing HomeScreen from (tabs)/index.tsx and then navigating to it, but that didn't work. I have also tried going specifically to (tabs)/index.tsx but that failed as well.
The code snippet with first attempt:


import HomeScreen from './(tabs)/index';


//other code

    const handleContinue = () => {
      if (Platform.OS === "web") {
        window.location.href = `${HomeScreen}?selectedTopics=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(selectedTopics))}`;
      } else {
        navigation.navigate('tabs', { screen: 'Home', params: { selectedTopics } });
      }
    };



Then the code snippet for the second attempt:


    const handleContinue = () => {
      if (Platform.OS === "web") {
        window.location.href = `/(tabs)/index?selectedTopics=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(selectedTopics))}`;
      } else {
        navigation.navigate('tabs', { screen: 'Home', params: { selectedTopics } });
      }
    };



When I try both of these, I get "This screen doesn't exist". What can I do to fix this problem?

Most of the time, the error is due to the fact that the screen is not yet loaded from the global Navigator of the app which wraps the tab and other kind of navigator in your project. Try to see how you have structured the navigation of your project or if you can share more code snippet on the navigation structure
